# How can I aggregate similar objects in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Given the following sample data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6325bc0cb945ffbfd7d2"), "Value1" : 297138463, "hostname" : "server1", "time" : 1385128741.221214 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6325bc0cb945ffbfd7d3"), "Value1" : 312283635, "hostname" : "server2", "time" : 1385128741.24351 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6325bc0cb945ffbfd7d4"), "Value1" : 277946406, "hostname" : "server3", "time" : 1385128741.249723 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6325bc0cb945ffbfd7d5"), "Value1" : 300892042, "hostname" : "server4", "time" : 1385128741.255984 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6325bc0cb945ffbfd7d6"), "Value1" : 294501471, "hostname" : "server5", "time" : 1385128741.263583 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6361bc0cb947df5ff960"), "Value1" : 297187182, "hostname" : "server1", "time" : 1385128801.826883 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6361bc0cb947df5ff961"), "Value1" : 312331528, "hostname" : "server2", "time" : 1385128801.848045 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6361bc0cb947df5ff962"), "Value1" : 277987001, "hostname" : "server3", "time" : 1385128801.857552 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6361bc0cb947df5ff963"), "Value1" : 300924710, "hostname" : "server4", "time" : 1385128801.864611 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f6361bc0cb947df5ff964"), "Value1" : 294528575, "hostname" : "server5", "time" : 1385128801.8726 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f639ebc0cb949ef5db1d4"), "Value1" : 297212963, "hostname" : "server1", "time" : 1385128862.060666 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f639ebc0cb949ef5db1d5"), "Value1" : 312371013, "hostname" : "server2", "time" : 1385128862.083595 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f639ebc0cb949ef5db1d6"), "Value1" : 278014257, "hostname" : "server3", "time" : 1385128862.089885 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f639ebc0cb949ef5db1d7"), "Value1" : 300952539, "hostname" : "server4", "time" : 1385128862.095612 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f639ebc0cb949ef5db1d8"), "Value1" : 294572376, "hostname" : "server5", "time" : 1385128862.103005 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f63d9bc0cb94bc1e8eedd"), "Value1" : 297243502, "hostname" : "server1", "time" : 1385128921.73372 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f63d9bc0cb94bc1e8eede"), "Value1" : 312406080, "hostname" : "server2", "time" : 1385128921.755981 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f63d9bc0cb94bc1e8eedf"), "Value1" : 278041965, "hostname" : "server3", "time" : 1385128921.762048 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f63d9bc0cb94bc1e8eee0"), "Value1" : 301007401, "hostname" : "server4", "time" : 1385128921.767804 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("528f63d9bc0cb94bc1e8eee1"), "Value1" : 294599791, "hostname" : "server5", "time" : 1385128921.775356 }
```

I'd like to aggregate `Value1` for all the objects that occurred within a second of each other. Is this possible? `time` is seconds UTC since epoch.

Comment: You can't do cross-document comparisons in MongoDB aggregation, which is what it sounds like you'd need?

Comment: I think this would be very difficult to do in aggregation if it were possible, i.e. what if you have three docs 1 second apart from each, how do you aggregate those? You need custom logic outside of aggregation

Comment: So would it be best to just add some sort of "session" id to objects I'd like grouped? Or should I do my aggregation during the data collection and store that data alongside? That second option seems wrong for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all events in the same second this will work, assuming a collection named events:

```
db.events.group({
    $keyf: function (event) {
        return {
            seconds: Math.round(event.time)
        };
    },
    initial: {
        events: []
    },
    $reduce: function (event, result) {
        result.events.push(event);
    }
});
```

- $keyf - is for creating a key from a function instead of an existing field, use this to round/truncate the time to seconds
- initial - creates the initial reduced document for each group of records in the same second
- $reduce pushes each event object into the grouped result
- See [group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/group/) documentation for more options

And if by aggregate you mean sum then change to something like this:

```
db.events.group({
    $keyf: function (event) {
        return {
            seconds: Math.round(event.time)
        };
    },
    initial: {
        total: 0
    },
    $reduce: function (event, result) {
        result.total += event.Value1;
    }
});
```